# How can I force another program to not show any dialog when I run it with Process.Start()

Tags: c#, multithreading, messagebox, thread-sleep, process.start

I'm not sure if it's possible anyway. But my question is, can I force a program to not show any dialogs when I run it with `process.Start()`?

I have a program where I call another program in a `foreach` loop. It is a fileconverter. Unfortunately some files don't exist any more or the user gives the wrong filepath. If that happens, the converter shows an error with a messagebox. But i don't want to see that box, because if the user wants to convert 10000 files, but has the wrong path in settings, 10000 messagboxes appear and force the system to crash.

I have tried to kill these processes but they have the same name in the processes as the converter itself. I can handle it with a `Thread.Sleep` but then my mouse is flickering all the time while my thread is running. This is just a little bit better than the messageboxes.

If there is a way, I would be very thankful if you could tell me :)

Regards Schlinger

Comment: You can try [to close](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11729281/1997232) that MessageBox. Or try to find a designated for batch processing command line tool.

Comment: This is what i do at the moment, but for that i have to call Thread.sleep(50) and this is causing the mouse to flicker. If It flickers then everywhere, not only in my programm. If  i wouldn't sleep, it would kill my process that is converting the file and so no output would be generated.

Comment: What OS you're targeting?

Comment: It's windows 7 or higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's not possible. There is no built-in way to prevent *any* executable to show any dialog box.

Depending on the executable you're running, with some luck it might expose a command line version that accepts some `quiet` or `noui` parameter, but it's unlikely.

Or you could try programmatically closing those dialog boxes, as suggested.

Comment: Is there a way to force the mouse to hide while my thread is running and not show the mouse again before the thred is done?